# Prevent duplicate data inserted from checkboxlist VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, foreach, checkboxlist

Greeting!
I have checkboxlist item inside my web form. It's already working fine, but I want to prevent it from inserting the same data (duplicate) into table.
Here's my code :

```
Using conn2 As New SqlConnection()
        conn2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
            .ConnectionStrings("BackboneConnectionString").ConnectionString()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into EL_MstFunctionalNilai values(@IDFunc, @nik, @IDFuncParent, @IDFuncChild, @IDFuncMtr, '', '', '0')"
            cmd.Connection = conn2
            conn2.Open()
            For Each item As ListItem In CheckBoxList2.Items
                If item.Selected Then

                    Dim urutan As Int32 = GetNumberFunctional()
                    Dim str As String = item.Value.ToString

                    Dim strArr() As String = str.Split("_")
                    Dim IDFunctionalParent1 As String = strArr(0)
                    Dim IDFunctionalChild1 As String = strArr(1)
                    Dim IDFunctionalMtr1 As String = strArr(2)

                    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFunc", urutan)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nik", txtnik.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFuncMtr", IDFunctionalMtr1) 'mtr
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFuncParent", IDFunctionalParent1) 'parent 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFuncChild", IDFunctionalChild1) 'child

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                End If
            Next
            conn2.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

NB. 'nik' is Employee ID --> so 1 employee wont get duplicate data 
How do I check if 'IDFunctionalParent1' & 'IDFunctionalChild1' & 'IDFunctionalMtr1' is present in table (param: 'nik') before insert them into table?
cheers

Comment: Probably you should use `UNIQUE` constraint, or use `SELECT` query to look up existing values and use value comparison which skips insert operation while the value exists in database.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your insert statement

```
coalesce((select max(id)+1 from table),0)
```

if i put it on your code then

```
Insert into EL_MstFunctionalNilai values(coalesce((select max(id)+1 from EL_MstFunctionalNilai),0), @nik, @IDFuncParent, @IDFuncChild, @IDFuncMtr, '', '', '0')
```

0 is default value if return null

Comment: Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Comment: tell me more about function getNumberFunctional, maybe you can use it to do some increment

Comment: select top 1 (IDFunc)+1 as Next_No from EL_MstFunctionalNilai order by IDFunc desc . It's increment by 1

Comment: try select max (IDFunc)+1 as Next_No from EL_MstFunctionalNilai.
i assume IDFunc is integer right?